# Find the distance from each node to the k-nearest special nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, shortest-path

Please let me know if my question isn't phrased clearly and I'll try my best to rephrase!

We are given a large road-network (>1,000,000 nodes, >3,000,000 edges), this graph is unweighted and undirected. In this graph, we will select 1000 random nodes as 'police stations'.

To find the distance to the nearest police station **from each node**, I was able to solve it by implementing a multi-source BFS, where the police station nodes are added to the queue at the start. The complexity is then O(V+E) compared to O(V(V+E)) when running the normal BFS V times.

However, I can't think of a way to modify this algorithm to find the distance to the k-nearest police stations from each node, instead of just the nearest one.

I'd really really appreciate if you guys could suggest a suitable algorithm or point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can run BFS P times, once from every police station as the source.
We can maintain a heap of size k for every vertex to maintain the k closest police station distances from that vertex.

The time complexity will be O(P(V+E) + PVlogK).

To make it even more faster, we can run the P BFS in parallel to greatly reduce the time by as much as C times where C is the number of processor cores in the machine.

Another optimization is to store the distances between a vertex and all the police stations in a list rather than a heap.
We can then use count sort and get the closest k stations.
The complexity of this part will change to O(VP) from O(VPlogK).

Comment: Didn't get the rationale behind `VKlogP`. Shouldn't it be `O(K + PlogK)` assuming you're using a max-heap and building it takes O(k) and performing a heapify for P times in the worst case would cost O(PlogK)?

Comment: @Siddharth Yes you are right. Thanks for pointing. Corrected it.

Comment: @LeeJunWei You are correct. We are not building any heap from array initially. Sorry for the confusion. I think I got a bit clumsy computing the complexity. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Adjust the algorithm so it continues after finding the nearest police station.

IE: Add the police station to a list and continue. Treat it as if it was a normal node. Only stop when you have found K police stations.

Looking at [Wikipedia for BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) we find this general algorithm:

```
 1  procedure BFS(G, root) is
 2      let Q be a queue
 3      label root as discovered
 4      Q.enqueue(root)
 5      while Q is not empty do
 6          v := Q.dequeue()
 7          if v is the goal then
 8              return v
 9          for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
10              if w is not labeled as discovered then
11                  label w as discovered
12                  Q.enqueue(w)
```

To allow us to search for police stations we just need to add some steps:

1. After line 3: Along with a Queue, and a Set (though there are other ways, IE: boolean array for numbered nodes) to store discovered nodes, we need a set to store discovered police stations.
2. Remove lines 7 and 8. We no longer have a specific goal we are seeking in terms of a node.
3. Add after line 10: If `w` is a police station, then add to `police station discovered set`. If the new size of the `police stations discovered set` is `K`, return the `police stations discovered set`.

Oh right, you need the distances, so when adding a police station to the discovered set, also add the distance to the list of police station distances (which is an array you'll have to add at the start of the algorithm too).

Comment: Hmmmm, There's some improvement you can make there but scratching by head to find one that is better more than a few times faster, but seems like the best option is probably just  `O(P(V + E))`, same idea but start from the police stations instead. Then for each node find the nearest K police stations (after finding the distance from each node to each police station). This approach is in theory 3000X faster than my answer (though still probably 1000X slower than what you have now). Hmmm wait a minute.

Comment: Hmmm, I was thinking we might be able to do something with hypergraphs. Basically collapsing nodes. IE: ABCDE if B,C,D each only have 2 edges. Then we can collapse those vertices and edges into a single A-E edge with weight being the sum of the collapsed edges. This can likely be used to reduce work, but unclear by how much. I don't think you can avoid using one of the two algorithms above, but you *can* avoid doing the same exact distance calculations multiple times and following the same path multiple times. I imagine collapsing 2 edge paths, would help a lot.